# WPF Binding to parent DataContext ignoring DataContext of the current element

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to bind [Visibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx) property of FirstDate and SecondDate [StackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel) to parent's [DataContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext) but instead, it binds to [DataContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext) of the current element. How can I ignore this [DataContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext) and set binding to the parent's [DataContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext)?

Also, MonthList must ignore the parent's [DataContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext) but it doesn't do that.

```
<StackPanel 
    DataContext="{Binding dateOfProduction}"
    Orientation="Vertical"
    Grid.Row="10"
    Grid.Column="1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton Content="One date" Margin="5,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DateType, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=OneDate}"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Two date" Margin="5,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DateType, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=TwoDate}"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Not exists" Margin="5,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DateType, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Empty}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=FirstDate}" Visibility="{Binding FirstDateExist, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Width="37" Content="Day" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="19" Text="{Binding Path=Day}"/>
        <Label Width="46" Content="Month" />
        <ComboBox Width="60"  ItemsSource="{Binding MonthList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Month}"/>
        <Label Width="29" Content="Year" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="32" Text="{Binding Path=Year}"/>
        <Label Width="30" Content="Hour" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="19" Text="{Binding Path=Hour}"/>
        <Label Width="51" Content="Minute" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="19" Text="{Binding Path=Minute}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=SecondDate}" Visibility="{Binding SecondDateExist, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Width="37" Content="Day" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="19" Text="{Binding Path=Day}"/>
        <Label Width="46" Content="Month" />
        <ComboBox Width="60"  ItemsSource="{Binding MonthList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Month}"/>
        <Label Width="29" Content="Year" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="32" Text="{Binding Path=Year}"/>
        <Label Width="30" Content="Hour" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="19" Text="{Binding Path=Hour}"/>
        <Label Width="51" Content="Minute" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="19" Text="{Binding Path=Minute}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Below you can see the classes used

```
public class GoodsDate : PropertyChangedModels
{
    private ComplexDate _FirstDate;
    public ComplexDate FirstDate
    {
        get { return _FirstDate; }
        set { _FirstDate = value; OnPropertyChanged("FirstDate"); }
    }

    private ComplexDate _SecondDate;
    public ComplexDate SecondDate
    {
        get { return _SecondDate; }
        set { _SecondDate = value; OnPropertyChanged("SecondDate"); }
    }
    public bool FirstDateExist
    {
        get => (FirstDate != null);
    }
    public bool SecondDateExist
    {
        get => (SecondDate != null);
    }
}  
public class ComplexDate : PropertyChangedModels
{
    public ComplexDate(int? year = null, int? month = null, int? day = null, int? hour = null, int? minute = null)
    {
        Year = year;
        Month = month;
        Day = day;
        Hour = hour;
        Minute = minute;
    }
    private int? _Year;
    public int? Year
    {
        get { return _Year; }
        set { _Year = value?.LimitToRange(1000, 2999); OnPropertyChanged("Year"); }
    }

    private int? _Month;
    public int? Month
    {
        get { return _Month; }
        set { _Month = value?.LimitToRange(1, 12); OnPropertyChanged("Month"); }
    }

    private int? _Day;
    public int? Day
    {
        get { return _Day; }
        set { _Day = value?.LimitToRange(1, 31); OnPropertyChanged("Day"); }
    }

    private int? _Hour;
    public int? Hour
    {
        get { return _Hour; }
        set { _Hour = value?.LimitToRange(0, 23); OnPropertyChanged("Hour"); }
    }

    private int? _Minute;
    public int? Minute
    {
        get { return _Minute; }
        set { _Minute = value?.LimitToRange(0, 59); OnPropertyChanged("Minute"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `DataContext="{Binding Path=FirstDate}"` and change the Bindings from e.g. `Text="{Binding Path=Day}"` to `Text="{Binding FirstDate.Day}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, you have defined the DataContext as `DataContext="{Binding Path=FirstDate}"` on First/SecondDate so the `Visibility` Property is trying to resolve it from set DataContext.

There are various solutions of your problem. You can implement one of mentioned

**1.** 
Use the Relative Source on Visiblity Property to set the binding to Parent.

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=FirstDateExist, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

**2.**

Wrap the StackPanel to Grid and set the Visiblity on it. In that case Visiblity will bind to DataContext of Top stackpanel.

```
<Grid  Visibility="{Binding FirstDateExist, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
     <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=FirstDate}" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Width="37" Content="Day" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="19" Text="{Binding Path=Day}"/>
        <Label Width="46" Content="Month" />
        <ComboBox Width="60"  ItemsSource="{Binding MonthList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Month}"/>
        <Label Width="29" Content="Year" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="32" Text="{Binding Path=Year}"/>
        <Label Width="30" Content="Hour" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="19" Text="{Binding Path=Hour}"/>
        <Label Width="51" Content="Minute" />
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="19" Text="{Binding Path=Minute}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**3.**

Remove `DataContext="{Binding Path=FirstDate}"` and change cascaded control bindings as `Text="{Binding FirstDate.Day}"`